# OAUTH2 - Login to Google Account - No Services needed

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, google-account

It would be great if somebody could help me with strategic input, how to achieve my goal:

- I wrote a C# Desktop Application (WPF)
- I have a Google App Engine Project, which delivers Data for an Android App

Now my Desktop Application needs to pass some Data to my App Engine Application. Therefore, the Application must authenticate as Owner of the App Engine Application. As, all other Google Methods are deprecated, I have to go heading OAUTH2 to let my Desktop App authenticate itself as owner.

Therefore I have to register a project at Google Apis Console.

**BUT**:
I dont need any Service(s) of the listed Google APIS (Maps, ...), because to authenticate as Owner, its absolutely enough to sign in to a Google Account (GmailAccount, Google Account, whatever). This lets my App Engine App recognize me as Owner.

I would appreciate advice about:

- Should I register a project without Service just to Sign In via OAUTH2?
  (Is this possible?)
- Sign in to another Service (means, taking the easiest way, just to be able to authenticate as Owner) seems not to be  very "clean" sollution. Is this right, or should I go this way?

.. I also read about Service Accounts, but dont want to use this, because I want to be able to manipulate my app also via my "Human"-Account via any Webbrowser.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide Google OAuth sign in without using any of Google's other services. Your OAuth client would just have an empty scope. You should be able to get the basic user info and email (so you can figure out who is who by something other than full name) without enabling any services as well.

You will still need a way to flag that you are you in your app (probably just hardcode your email in your app, then check it against who authenticates with OAuth would be the easiest)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was a little bit scared of playing around in the Api Console just to find out what works. If empty scope is possible, I will try to login the "installed way" programatically (think this will work somehow). As I enabled Roles in my App Engine Project, it must recognize me as Owner via the Cookie or the token as Owner (Think so, because when I loged in, .. as long the Browser is open, no matter if Google Page is open, I am Recognized as Owner) , ..but dont know yet, .. will let u know how I solved it.

Comment: As I said, I will let you know which way I did: After one more checking of all scenarios I decided to go heading OAuth1 because, .Net does not provide JSON/JWT at the moment (I know there are OS Libs, but I dont want to use  ist). Another point was, that I only needed one simple Request which made OAUTH2 oversized for me. As OAUTH1 is provided till 2015 I decided to go this way!